# How to remove allOf from json schema based on a json value

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv, react-jsonschema-forms

The following json schema works the following way ([DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-json-schema-form-example-forked-q6rsp8?file=/src/App.tsx)):

- If `switch` is true, `objectDependingOnSwitch` will have a string property called `switchIsTrue`.
- If `switch` is false, `objectDependingOnSwitch` will have a string property called `switchIsFalse`.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "switch": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "objectDependingOnSwitch": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "switch": {
            "const": true
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "objectDependingOnSwitch": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "switchIsTrue": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "switch": {
            "const": false
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "objectDependingOnSwitch": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "switchIsFalse": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to **remove the `allOf` property based on a given json value**?

For example, for following json value:

```json
{
  switch: true
}
```

I want the discriminatory json schema:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "switch": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "objectDependingOnSwitch": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "switchIsTrue": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to remove (and replace) the `allOf` keyword from the actual JSON Schema resource? If yes, this is nothing a validator would do for you.

Comment: Since the value of `switch` is `true`, I want to generate the final json schema discarding the second `allOf` case (where `switch` is `false`).